# Can user attributes such as Title, Company, Address, Phone etc be added/updated?

Tags: attributes, provisioning, google-provisioning-api

Does GoogleApps Provisioning API support adding/updating user attributes such as Title, Company, Address, Phone etc?

As far as I can tell, it only supports adding a user's username, password, IsSuspended status and quota.

Answer (score 0):

The [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/) is deprecated. You should be using the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started) which does support [updating all of those user fields.](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user)